# is it possible to generate Amazon SES credentials from existing amazon ec2 account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, credentials

we are using elastic email for sending emails to our customers

but due to some technical reasons our team wants to change that to Amazon SES,

we want to generate Amazon SES credentials using amazon ec2 account.

is it possible to generate the Amazon SES credentials from existing  Amazon ec2 account?

if yes please help me..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by generate credentials?? AWS comes with a feature called IAM, identity and access management, just have a look, I hope you are looking for the similar service,one can access the ses account using ses api or smtp settings.

Comment: generation means :is there any possibility to access the Amazon SES account through Amazon EC2..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the master credentials then the access key id and secret access key you use is valid for any part of amazon web services that you have signed up for (ec2, s3, ses, rds, ...).

It is  generally considered good practise to create IAM accounts with only the required permissions and use those credentials.

If you are using smtp access then you need to set that up from the ses web console - smtp uses a separate set of credentials.